# How can I get the overall stat change from many commits?

Tags: git

I'd like to do a `git log --grep` to get a list of commits and then find out what the overall `diff --stat` change is. I want a combined stat, as if all the commits were one commit. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Define "stat change", do you mean like with the `--stat` option?

Comment: @Zeeker yeah like --stat

Comment: I'm presuming you are getting back non-continuous commits?  I think you will have to generate individual stats for each commit, and then use some other logic (awk, python, etc.) to combine

Comment: @AndrewC most likely yes. I'm currently looking at 2 weeks of work on one ticket.

Comment: start with `for rev in $(git log --grep=YOUR_STRING) do git diff --stat ${rev}^1 > some_file`, then process that file to aggregate the results.

Answer (score 0):

git log --stat
The --stat option prints below each commit entry a list of modified files, how many files were changed, and how many lines in those files were added and removed. It also puts a summary of the information at the end.
Another really useful option is --pretty. This option changes the log output to formats other than the default.

Comment: maybe I wrote this confusingly? I want a combined stat of all the commits (like they were one commit)

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` will always generate a full changelog for all changes from one commit to another. To get the stat output you desire it makes the most sense to find the oldest commit from your `git log --grep` search and to compare this with a revision of your choice.

A command which compares the oldest "*grepped*" commit with the current `HEAD` could look like this:

```
git diff --stat $(git log --grep "<search-pattern>" --format='%H' | tail -1) HEAD
```

Hope this helps.